# Loading python-mode.el with use-package - still get python.el

Tags: emacs

I just discovered `use-package` and I'd like to use it with `python-mode.el`. I'm trying this:

```
(use-package python-mode
  :mode ("\\.py\\'" . python-mode)
  :interpreter ("python" . python-mode))
```

but am still getting `python.el` for `python-mode`. The `use-package` example specifically describes using `python.el` for `python-mode`, but I want the opposite. Can I accomplish that with `use-package`?

(I'm using GNU Emacs 24.5.1 on OS X if that's important.)

Comment: Have you solved this now ?

Comment: No, I never have. I refactored my Python stuff out to a separate library file but it's still executed at init time.

Comment: That annoyed my quite a lot. The same thing happened in org mode, I just can't use the `elpa` version of it ! And it seems that no anyone else cares about this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the keywords `:mode` and `:interpreter`. It works for me, like this:

```
(use-package python-mode
     :init
     ...
     :config
     ...)
```

Comment: I'd forgotten that I asked this. Yes, that's what worked for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution I found is there:
https://superuser.com/questions/108233/how-can-i-prevent-the-python-el-that-ships-with-emacs-23-from-ever-loading/999608#999608

In your `.emacs`, force the loading of the bad package first, then override it with the correct one:

```
(require 'python)
(require 'python-mode)
```